# Error installing DataStax OpsCenter while creating opscenter SSL files

Tags: datastax, opscenter

I downloaded the setup from [official site](https://academy.datastax.com/quick-downloads) and executed `./setup.py` but got following error

```
File "./setup.py", line 54
    print "Error when creating opscenter SSL files. Error was:\n"
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

any alternatives?

Comment: What version of Python are you running. Sounds like you're on 3.x and the setup.py file was written on 2.6. In 3.0 and better you need to call the print function as in print(). Open the file and add the parens wherever you see print and run it again